# Convert GridView.DataSource with DateTime column to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I'm trying eventually to sort the gridview, But when I convert:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridAllTests.DataSource;
```

There's an exeption - can't convert object DateTime to String.

The datasource comes from database sql server, using Entity
GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridAllTests" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
DataKeyNames="testId" AllowSorting="true">

 <Columns>    
    <asp:BoundField DataField="courseName" HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="courseName"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="onDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="onDate" 
        DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="false"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lastRegisterDate" HeaderText="LastDate" 
        SortExpression="lastRegisterDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="false"/>   
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" runat="server" text="Register" 
            CommandName="Register" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("testId") %>' />
            <asp:Literal ID="litAlreadyRegisterd" runat="server" Text="Registered"/>
            <asp:Literal ID="litTooLate" runat="server" Text="Registration Over"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

SecondTestEntities1 db = new SecondTestEntities1();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            User currUser = (User)Session["user"];
            gridAllTests.DataSource = from test in db.Tests
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         testId= test.TestId,
                                         courseName = test.Course.Name,
                                         onDate = test.OnDate,
                                         lastRegisterDate = test.LastRegisterDate
                                     };
            try
            {
                gridAllTests.DataBind();
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridAllTests.DataSource;
                Session["taskTable"] = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblError.Text = err.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (gridAllTests.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Please put more codes . like gridAllTests.DataSource=??? what ?

Comment: `DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridAllTests.DataSource;`

What is your `datasource` ??Are you sure its Datatable???

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
          DataView dv=(DataView) from test in db.Tests
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         testId= test.TestId,
                                         courseName = test.Course.Name,
                                         onDate = test.OnDate,
                                         lastRegisterDate = test.LastRegisterDate
                                     };
         gridAllTests.DataSource = dv;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();      

        DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = (DataView)dv.Select(args);// This SqlDataSourceObject means your sql query return object ,like dataset or dataview, etc

        dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: Same problem, can't use dv for that query

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your date objects to strings

```
test.OnDate.ToString(//format here);

test.LastRegisterDate.ToString(//format here);
```

I think I've come across a similar issue where DataTable doesn't know how to deal with DateTime objects.

Comment: Where should i add that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            User currUser = (User)Session["user"];
           //  Dataset dsGrdDource = new Dataset();
            IEnumerable<DataRow> result = from test in db.Tests
                                  select new
                               {
                                  testId= test.TestId,
                                  courseName = test.Course.Name,
                                  onDate = test.OnDate.ToShortDateString() ,
                                  lastRegisterDate = test.LastRegisterDate
                               };

          DataTable dtgrdSource= query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
       try
         { 

                 gridAllTests.DataSource =dtgrdSource;
                 gridAllTests.DataBind();
               //  DataTable dt = (DataTable)dsGrdDource.Tables[0];
                Session["taskTable"] = dtgrdSource;
            } 

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblError.Text = err.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

If you are using `ToShortDateString()` do not apply formatting at `boundfield` as datetime formatting can not be applied to strings . 
If you do not wish to use `ToShortDateString()` just try above code without `ToShortDateString()` and use formatting at BoundField.

Comment: Tried that and got: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gridAllTests'.  Remove one definition

Comment: @Nuni I hope it's your full aspx code and you are not using any `DatasourceId` in your design page .Well i have updated answer check if it works .

Comment: However i do not understand why your code is trying to convert DateTime to string.

Comment: I'm not using DatasourceId in design page. Is there other way to display only the date, without using the convert DateTime to string? Anyway, I get this Error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Yes because when you are using `New` keyword in your query it is creating these objects with anonymous type (Sorry) , Instead of ` IEnumerable<DataRow> result` try using `Var` keyword as `Var result=`        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

Comment: No need to convert it to `string`  ` DataFormatString="{0:d}"` do not handle string .  Try using `dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" `